# Transition effects between activities in android

Tags: android, android-transitions

On a `button click`, I want to go to an `activity` which is not written by me `(such as ACTION_DIAL)` and at the same time I want to control it's `transition effects`.

I am able to control `transition effect` at opening of the activity by using `overridePendingTransition`, but I am unable to control the `transition effect` when I come back to the same page by pressing the `backbutton`.

I want the same effect `(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)` to happen during start and finish of the activity, which is not happening as of now. It's working only at the start.

I am adding the code snippet below. Please have a look and help me out. :)

```
case R.id.button1:intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

                             startActivity(intent);
                             overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                             break;
case R.id.button2:intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
                            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                             startActivity(intent);
                             overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                             break;
```

Comment: just add your transition effect code in `onResume()` and `onPause()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you SaravInfern for your help. But your solution won't help me because I am using the onBackPressed() function for doing some other operation.

However I was able to find solution myself, thanks to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

I added the 'overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)' line inside onResume and onPause functions as follow which solved the issue for me.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    super.onPause();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your activity

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

or 
simply this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```